# Magento - Hide specific attribute from specific category page

Tags: php, magento

Does somebody know how to hide an attribute from a specific category page?
I got a tip from the company that build my layered navigation module that 
it could be done trough css and the unique category body class but how???

This is my body class

```
<body class=" catalog-category-view categorypath-jongenskleding-html category-jongenskleding">
```

Comment: I suspect, that if you accepted answers and upvoted that you found helpful then more people would be inclined to help you on stack overflow.  You haven't accepted any answers yet.

Comment: sorry I did not know that could be done, I am new to stackoverflow ;-)